# Resource files in a web based javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, runtime

I'm starting with javascript and HTML5 game programming, and the very first trouble I found is about the resource files.

While my game has tons of MB in images and sounds, it will be both to the server and to the client to download them every time the game starts.

So, **in a general approach**, how can I save all the needed files to a local folder and recover them on runtime?

Comment: concatenate them (using sprites for images), compress them, let them be cached.

Comment: How about using the HTML5 application cache? html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner

Comment: Download only data for current level at current time. Cache files that you will need soon. Caching images is browser default behavior, take care about http headers if you have a chance to change them. You can use local storage (for images in base64), but you have limit 5MB in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to save files to a local folder and then use them from your website - for security reasons the browser does not allow that.

If you want to deliver the game as a website, and not something the user downloads and runs locally, what you can do is to set far future expire-headers on all your content, which will tell the browser to cache the content until that date. Your user will then not have to download the resources the next time he visit your site to play the game.

Yahoo has [some good reads](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires) on website performance that discuss this.

For performance, you should also make sure that you enable gzip, which can greatly reduce the amount of data that has to be sent in response to a request. Especially important if you have large quantities of data to download.

As your question is tagged HTML5, you can also have a look at the [HTML5 application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache), which lets you cache various resources locally, including images, audio etc. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) is a good resource/tutorial to get you started. It is worth noting though that the application cache has limited support in older browsers, while expire headers has been supported for quite some time. So depending on the browser support you need, you will have to consider what approach to take.